# Order Results by Related Table Count - Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a database with the following items/relationships.

- "questions" -> "answers" -> "responses"
- "responses" each belong to a single "industry"

I'm retrieving data with Eloquent ORM using the query below:

```
$questions = Question::where('public', '=', '1')
    ->where('question', 'like', "%$query%")
    ->whereHas('responses', function($q) use($industry_id) {
            $q->where('industry_id', '=', $industry_id);
        })->get();
```

Works great and retrieves questions that are marked as public, match the user's search, and have responses from the appropriate industry.

The problem is, I can't seem to find a way to sort the results based on on the number of responses with the appropriate industry ID.  I need to count the responses to the question with the right industry ID then sort the questions by that number.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to order by related table is to join it, because of the way Eloquent handles relational queries.

```php
$questions = Question::where('public', '=', '1')
  ->where('question', 'like', "%$query%")
  ->join('answers as a', 'a.question_id', '=', 'questions.id')
  ->join('responses as r', 'r.answer_id', '=', 'a.id')
  ->where('r.industry_id', $industry_id)
  ->orderByRaw('count(r.id) desc')
  ->select('questions.*')
  // or selectRaw('questions.*, count(r.id) as responses_count')
  ->groupBy('questions.id')
  ->get();
```